How to Apply Formulas Across the Values of Dynamic Arrays?
I am not the best Excel user in the world, so sorry if this is a basic question.
I'm trying to semi-automate expanding data received from a supplier to input into a receiving program. I have a solution that mostly works when handling data for a single line item, but am struggling to scale up the formulas to account for variable list lengths and dyanmic array sizes.
The data I receive will be in roughly this format:



RO
ROID
ITEM
CONT
RP
TALLY




P03865
46264
121012s
620243
2
1/10, 1/11


P03865
46265
121014s
620244
2
1/10, 1/11, 1/12



Where each row is going to contain information about a SKU and the "TALLY" field is going to contain a variable length of tallied items (i.e. line 1 contains 1 10ft piece and 1 11ft piece). The format I'm trying to manipulate the data into is roughly this (only including one line for brevity):



Received_qty
RO
ROID
ITEM
CONT
RP




21
P03865
46264
121012s
620243   1
2


10
P03865
46264
121012s   .10
620243
2


11
P03865
46264
121012s   .11
620243
2



RO, ROID, CONT, and RP columns will be static fields. The ITEM column will be repeated for every tallied length + 1 for a cumulative column. The received_qty is the product of each tally.
For repeating the product info I believe I can use a formula like =LEN(F2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(F2,"/","")) to parse the TALLY column, then use helper columns for repetition. I can use LEFT, RIGHT, and FIND formulas to parse the piece counts and tally lengths, and use math and concats for the items. I am comfortable with applying this to a sheet with one line item but not adapting the formulas to scale for additional line items that may have anywhere from 1 to 30 values in the TALLY column.

Assuming you have Microsoft 365, enter the following where you want the result (with enough empty rows below). The example shown uses a dynamics range (B6#) for the data parameter.



Step
Line




Data range is specified in parameter data, either as a regular range or a dynamic one
LAMBDA(data,


To process rows, get an array indices
row_indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),


Build the result in result using REDUCE by stacking built rows for each row
result, REDUCE(


Set the header as the initial value.
TEXTSPLIT("Received_qty,RO,ROID,ITEM,CONT,RP", ",")


For each row, accessing row by index
row_indices, LAMBDA(acc_res, cur_row,


using INDEX collect the columns in variables
LET(ro, INDEX(data, cur_row, 1), roid, INDEX(data, cur_row, 2), item, INDEX(data, cur_row, 3), cont, INDEX(data, cur_row, 4), rp, INDEX(data, cur_row, 5), tally, INDEX(data, cur_row, 6),


get quantity lengths by splitting the tally column
qty_lengths,  TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(tally), ",")]


In result_0, build the rows for the current row using these lengths (qty_lengths), using REDUCE again.
result_0, REDUCE(


for each value in qty_lengths (for example 1/10)
qty_lengths, LAMBDA(acc, cur,


get quantity and length by splitting
LET(qty_len, TEXTSPLIT(cur, "/"), qty, INDEX(qty_len, , 1), len, INDEX(qty_len, , 2)


build the row according your need
row_, HSTACK(qty * len, ro, roid, CONCAT(item, ".", len), "" & cont, rp)


stack the built rows
VSTACK(acc, row_)


after handling the tally for the current row, add the cumulative row
cumulative_row, HSTACK(SUM(INDEX(result_0, , 1)), ro, roid, item, CONCAT(cont, " ", 1), rp)


accumulate the results by stacking the rows , dropping the the initial "cumulative row" as we don't need it.
result, VSTACK(cumulative_row, DROP(result_0, 1))



=LAMBDA(data,
    LET(
        row_indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
        result, REDUCE(
            TEXTSPLIT("Received_qty,RO,ROID,ITEM,CONT,RP", ","),
            row_indices,
            LAMBDA(acc_res, cur_row,
                LET(
                    ro, INDEX(data, cur_row, 1),
                    roid, INDEX(data, cur_row, 2),
                    item, INDEX(data, cur_row, 3),
                    cont, INDEX(data, cur_row, 4),
                    rp, INDEX(data, cur_row, 5),
                    tally, INDEX(data, cur_row, 6),
                    qty_lengths, TEXTSPLIT(TRIM(tally), ","),
                    result_0, REDUCE(
                        "cumulative_row",
                        qty_lengths,
                        LAMBDA(acc, cur,
                            LET(
                                qty_len, TEXTSPLIT(cur, "/"),
                                qty, INDEX(qty_len, , 1),
                                len, INDEX(qty_len, , 2),
                                row_, HSTACK(
                                    qty * len,
                                    ro,
                                    roid,
                                    CONCAT(item, ".", len),
                                    "" & cont,
                                    rp
                                ),
                                VSTACK(acc, row_)
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                    cumulative_row, HSTACK(
                        SUM(INDEX(result_0, , 1)),
                        ro,
                        roid,
                        item,
                        CONCAT(cont, " ", 1),
                        rp
                    ),
                    result, VSTACK(
                        cumulative_row,
                        DROP(result_0, 1)
                    ),
                    VSTACK(acc_res, result)
                )
            )
        ),
        result
    )
)(B6#)



Hi! Thank you so much for the suggestion. This works very well, but I had a pair of questions.


Could you provide an explanation of this formula? I think I understand most of this..


Is it possible to pass along a dynamic range to this formula without converting it into a VBA function or subprocedure? :)



Added some explanation and also made it easier to specify data as a parameter. You can make the lambda a named function after testing, making it available in all the sheets in the workbook. No need for VBA here. Please let me know if any part needs further clarification :)
